# Grouping duplicates in Pandas on 2 ids and transforming the rest of columns in different ways

Tags: python, pandas

For the sake of this question, let's suppose we have 2 shops and an inventory in Pandas with duplicate entries. We identify each item on its bar code and the date it arrived to the shop (so we will consider different items if the date is different, even if the bar code is the same), and we store the stock of each item in each shop, and the price:

```
      arrival_date   bar_code   stock_shop1   stock_shop2   price
1       2015-08-30    8000001            52            11     100
2       2015-08-30    8000001            48             0      85
3       2015-09-11    8000001            10            20      95
4       2015-10-04    8000002             5            10      50
5       2015-10-04    8000002            30            25      49
```

We want to group by arrival date and bar code, and:

1. Sum the stock of each store
2. Set the minimum price (we are on sales and we want to make the same offer in both stores)

So we should get:

```
      arrival_date   bar_code   stock_shop1   stock_shop2   price
1       2015-08-30    8000001           100            11      85
2       2015-09-11    8000001            10            20      95
3       2015-10-04    8000002            35            35      49
```

I have seen several similar questions, even with two ids, but I have not found if it is possible to sum some columns and keep the maximum or minimum value in other columns. I guess it is possible, I just don't know how.

I have tried:

```
df.join(df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code'])(['stock_shop1', 'stock_shop2']).sum(), on=['arrival_date', 'bar_code'], rsuffix='_r')
```

Just to check if I can at least group by both 'arrival_date' and 'bar_code' and sum the stock columns, but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' obejct is not callable
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do, in `agg` you can mention which aggregation rule ot be applied on each column.

```
In [121]: (df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code'])
             .agg({'stock_shop1': np.sum, 'stock_shop2': np.sum, 'price': np.min})
           )
Out[121]:
                       price  stock_shop1  stock_shop2
arrival_date bar_code
2015-08-30   8000001      85          100           11
2015-09-11   8000001      95           10           20
2015-10-04   8000002      49           35           35
```

Comment: Note that there's no need for the `np.` here; we automatically delegate to the numpy version if appropriate, so either `sum` or `'sum'` etc. would have worked equally well.

Comment: Absolutely, was giving a hint, certain numpy methods could be used beyond max, min, sum

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to call the `Groupby object` as - `df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code'])(..)` - Hence the issue.

You also do not need to use `DataFrame.join` , you can simply do `groupby` and then `.aggregate()` (or `.agg()` ) for the multiple columns. Example -

```
df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code']).agg({'stock_shop1':sum,'stock_shop2':sum,'price':min})
```

If you do not want the `'arrival_date'` and `'bar_code'` as indexes, you can call `.reset_index()` , to reset the index. Example -

```
df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code']).agg({'stock_shop1':sum,'stock_shop2':sum,'price':min}).reset_index()
```

Demo -

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  arrival_date  bar_code  stock_shop1  stock_shop2  price
1   2015-08-30   8000001           52           11    100
2   2015-08-30   8000001           48            0     85
3   2015-09-11   8000001           10           20     95
4   2015-10-04   8000002            5           10     50
5   2015-10-04   8000002           30           25     49

In [15]: df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code']).agg({'stock_shop1':sum,'stock_shop2':sum,'price':min})
Out[15]:
                       stock_shop2  stock_shop1  price
arrival_date bar_code
2015-08-30   8000001            11          100     85
2015-09-11   8000001            20           10     95
2015-10-04   8000002            35           35     49

In [16]: df.groupby(['arrival_date', 'bar_code']).agg({'stock_shop1':sum,'stock_shop2':sum,'price':min}).reset_index()
Out[16]:
  arrival_date  bar_code  stock_shop2  stock_shop1  price
0   2015-08-30   8000001           11          100     85
1   2015-09-11   8000001           20           10     95
2   2015-10-04   8000002           35           35     49
```